# Pandas Mean and Merge Two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I need to get the means for plus merge based on their original column names.  An example is this:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
'sepal_length': [5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0],
'sepal_width': [3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4],
'petal_length': [1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5],
'petal_width': [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2]
 })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'sepal_length': [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2],
'sepal_width': [3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4],
'petal_length': [1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5],
'petal_width': [1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5]
})
```

I get the means like this:

```
df_one=df.mean(axis=0).to_frame('Mean_One')
df_two=df2.mean(axis=0).to_frame('Mean_Two')
```

The question is how to merge these two datagrams (df_one and df_two) since there is no column name for the original petal info (e.g., sepal_length, sepal_width, etc.). If there were I could do this

```
 pd.merge(df_one, df_two, on='?')
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.concat[df_one, df_two], axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly you're trying to join the two averaged dataframes to have a column of average measurements for each of the dataframes.

If that's the case then you can join using their indexes:

```py
pd.merge(df_one, df_two, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
                Mean_One  Mean_Two
sepal_length    4.9125    0.2375
sepal_width     3.3875    3.3875
petal_length    1.4500    1.4500
petal_width     0.2375    1.4500
```

Comment: thanks...makes sense..one other question, after the merge is there a way to identify the first column, since it has no name.

Comment: The first 'column' of names is now the index for the DF.

Comment: @Allen What do you mean by "identify the first column"? After the merge the column names are `['Mean_One', 'Mean_Two']`.

Comment: You could use the new index using eg `print(new_df.loc['sepal_length', :])`